# Heptagonal tesselations

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tessellations

Are there any tesselations of the Euclidean plane that use only regular polygons such that one of them is a heptagon?

If so, what is the tesselation that uses the fewest different types of polygon possible?

Comment: No, a regular heptagon can't tesselate with any other set of regular polygons.  The reason is that its interior angle ($5\pi /7$) can't be combined with the interior angles of other regular polygons to form $2\pi$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: it ought to be an answer, instead of hyperbolic off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The hyperbolic plane is another matter, here is a tesselation that includes  regular heptagons.